# Haskell and postgresql-libpq

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

I've some issue with postgresql-libpq (Windows x32 OS).

I am trying to execute either one 'ghci -package postgresql-libpq' or 'yesod devel' in my the project directory I got the such error "Entry point into libintl_gettext not found in DLL libintl.dll library."

Why am I seeing this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like libintl.dll isn't installed / isn't in your path properly. It seems to be an occasional problem with postgres in general on windows: http://blog.kimiensoftware.com/2011/07/windows-postgresql-and-the-case-of-the-vanishing-libint-dll-372